# \bibunits errors in a twocolumn memoir

Tags: two-column, bibunits

First, I am having trouble generating a MWE at this moment. I will continue to try get one set up. In the meantime, I am hoping someone will recognize the problem based on my description:

I have a paper with two `bibunit` environments from the `bibunits` package. When I am writing and editing, I have the document prepared in `twocolumn` format, but I switch to a single column for my boss to review.

Yesterday, both column counts worked fine. Today's draft, however, has errors when I try to compile with `twocolumn` enabled. The errors in the bu1.aux file:

```
You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode \@
Missing $ inserted \@
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode \@
```

or in the .tex file at the line containing `\end{bibunit}`:

```
Extra }, or forgotten $ \end{bibunit}
Missing $ inserted \end{bibunit}
Missing } inserted \end{bibunit}
```

When I look at the error lines in bu1.aux, I see this:

```
\@LN@col{1}
\@LN@col{2}
```

I thought I'd fix it by flanking my `\end{bibunit}` command with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, which indeed stopped the errors but resulted in my first citation in that bibunit having `LN@col2LN@col1LN@col2LN@col1` in front of it (in the output pdf).

I'm out of ideas. If can get a MWE without having to post my paper, I will do so ASAP.

EDIT: I figured out the problem was a conflict with the `lineno` package which numbers lines. Commenting out that packaged fixed the problem. *But* I'd still like to know how to fix the conflict. I will still try to get an MWE if it helps people solve this problem.

Comment: Without some form of example, this is going to be very tricky to answer. Clearly the `lineno` package does work, so there must be something more specific going on. Without an example I'm afraid it's 'unclear'.